# How is std::time_t different from time point in C++?

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono

How is [`std::time_t`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time_t/) different from [`time point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/now) representing the current time?

Are they not the same thing i.e epoch from same start Jan 1  1970?

Comment: Looks like `time_point` gives you a lot more flexibility in the internal representation.  It's not always an integer containing seconds.

Comment: Also see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M not only for a tutorial, but also for a rationale of why `time_point` and `duration` exist.

Answer (score 2):

`std::time_t`, as the reference says, ends up being an arithmetic type (i.e. `int`, `long`, `unsigned long long`, etc.). `time_point` is a templated structure that allows many different operations on top of arithmetic, like converting into a different time unit (i.e. `milliseconds`, using `time_point_cast`).

Comment: Just summarizing for my notes : time point is a template which offers lots of operations including function to get time since epoch. time_t is a integral representation of time point indicating time in secs since epoch. Struct tm is a component wise breakdown of datetime. mktime can be used to convert tm structure to time_t and its reverse can be achieved by localtime which can convert time_t to struct tm.

Comment: Yes; and regarding the `tm` structure: there's also more modern equivalents inside [`chrono` library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) since C++20, including calendar and time zones utilities.